# custom fortran function similar to write

Tags: fortran

I have a fortran program with a lot of statements like this:

```
write(0,*) '*** ERROR *** something went wrong ',i
write(0,*) '*** ERROR *** something happend in line ',i
write(0,*) '*** ERROR *** something happend in line ',i,' of file ',filename
```

Is it possible to create a custom subroutine, e.g. `log_error(msg)` that allows the same arbitrary number and types of input as `write`?

Comment: You come up against the fundamental difference between the `write` statement and functions/subroutines.  They are simply not the same thing at all.  [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45261155/3157076) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19906446/3157076) may provide you with some hints.